# Set Laravel Collective Select default input as disabled

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, materialize, laravelcollective

Part of my **PostController.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Session;
    use Carbon\Carbon;

    use App\Category;
    use App\Post;
    use App\Tag;
    use App\User;


    class PostController extends Controller
    {
    public function create()
      {
        $categories = Category::pluck('name','id');
        $tags = Tag::pluck('name','id');

        return view('posts.create')->withCategories($categories)->withTags($tags); 
      }
```

Part of my **posts/create.blade.php**

```
 <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
   {!! Form::select('category', $categories, null, ['class' => 'validate', 'placeholder' => 'test']) !!}
   {{ Form::label('category', 'Category: ') }}
 </div>
```

I'm using Laravel Collective to create my forms with Blade Syntax, and I'm using [Materialize CSS](http://materializecss.com/select.html).

It all works and submits, but at the minute it has the first item in the `$categories` array automatically selected, and I'd like this to not be the case.

I'm trying to have a `disabled` placeholder that's `selected` and says "Select your category".

I'm not sure if this is possible?

I know I don't have to use the blade syntax, and can just create a normal HTML form, but this project is entirely for learning purposes, as I'm trying to learn Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by creating the placeholder yourself:

```
{!! Form::select('category', ['' => 'Select your category'] + $categories->all(), null,
    ['class' => 'validate'], ['' => ['disabled']]) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
"class" => "first-disabled "
```

to your select and then `\`

Use this code in the scripts and it will disable it: `\`

```
$( "select.first-disabled option:first-child" ).attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try: [**prepend**](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-prepend)

```
return view('posts.create')->withCategories($categories->prepend('Select category', ''))->withTags($tags);
```

Hope it help you !!!